# Using the cases environment in LyX

Tags: latex, lyx

In LyX, how does one add multiple cases to a cases environment?

When I insert the cases template, I get the opening bracket followed by two placeholder boxes, i.e.

> {□□

I can put as much math in those two placeholders as I want, but I haven't been able to figure out how to add *rows* to this environment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try Shift+Enter or Control+Enter.

Comment: Cmd+Enter on Macs

Answer (score 1):

In LyX, there is an *Add Row* button close to the *Case Environment* button. It is unavailable  before being in the case environment, but it does the job afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

within the Google Document editor this problem also occurs and

```
\begin{cases}
1st\\
2nd\\
3rd\end{cases}
```

worked for me.